# Exporting chart with Highchart display a badly formed chart

Tags: highcharts, export

Playing around with HighChart, I am unable to make a user-friendly export, when i export my chart, all data are too compressed to be human readable,bar are too clause from each others. See image at bottom.

I have try to use ChartOption, export, width, scale, but didn't work at this time.

Can somebody propose me an idea?

[image: Example]

Comment: You are going to need to provide some representative code, images, or example output desired before we can hope to answer this question.

Comment: I tried to put my exported IMG but i can't because of my reputation on stackoverflow, it's the first time I request help .... !

Comment: You can post your code, though. Or a jsFiddle showing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can define size ([width](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.sourceWidth),
[height](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.sourceHeight), [scale](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.scale)) of your exporting file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, As you said Sebastian Bochan we can play with the size in exporting option, but width, height, scale are usefull for resolution but it was not the real width of the exported img.

We have to use sourceWidth, because after digging in exporting.js I noticed that by default if exporting JS is unable to retrieve the size of a chart, it assume 600*600, that was my problem, and that's why my chart look compressed.

By explicitly defining the size with SOURCEWIDTH you can bypass this behavior, but i didn't find why exporting.js is unable to retrieve the original size by himself....

but now i have a full of beauty chart with 60 bar displayed over 1400px, i'm happy !

Thanks for your answer,